# Firestore query cache

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have 1 method in my repository in which I receive a status. Either this status is 0 or 1. If it is 0 I need to generate a different query than if it is 1, let's say

```
fun getData(status:Int) {
 val docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("orders")
 if(status == 0){
  docRef.whereEqualTo("status",0)
 }else{
  docRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("status",1).whereLessThan("status",4)
}

 val suscription = docRef.addSnapshotListener { ... }
```

Now, I use this method to either query with status 0 or status 1 different documents in my collection, now, when I come back where status is 0 in my UI, will Firestore cache this two queries and return me the cached docRef of status 0? or it will be requiring all the documents again because is in the same method and there are not two different docRefs?

I wonder this because I have a bottomnavigation where I switch tabs, I don't want to require the data if its already queried.

I want to know if this conditional If statement will cache the two queries into my client when I need either the first one or the second one below

### Edit

This question is because if I need to create a separate method with all the same data but with a different reference to hold the data

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your method should look like this:

```
fun getData(status:Int) {
    val docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("orders")
    if(status == 0){
        docRef = docRef.whereEqualTo("status",0)
    } else {
        docRef = docRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("status",1).whereLessThan("status",4)
    }
}
val suscription = docRef.addSnapshotListener { /* ... */ }
```

And this because Cloud Firestore queries are immutable, which means that you cannot change the properties of an existing query. If you change the value by calling `.whereEqualTo("status",0)` method, it becomes a new query.

> Firestore cache these two queries and return me the cached docRef of status 0?

Firestore will cache all the documents that are returned by your query. If the `if part` of the statement is triggered, then you'll have in the cache only those documents, otherwise you'll have the other ones.

> I want to know if this conditional If statement will cache the two queries into my client when I need either the first one or the second one below

If you switch between both tabs and both queries are executed, you'll have all the documents from both queries cached.